# Proof that : $f$ is continously differentiable $\Leftrightarrow |f(x + h) - f(x + t) - l(h - t)| \leq \epsilon |h-t|$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Prove: $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable if and only if for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists a $l \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for every $h,t \in B(0, \delta)$:

$|f(x + h) - f(x + t) - l(h - t)| \leq \epsilon |h-t|$

I've tried quite alot of stuff, but I just can't get to this solution. Also tried to use Lipschitz but that didn't help much either.

I know that this question is on here already,  but I don't understand that answer.

Comment: Link the answer you've already found and mention what don't you understand there.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If $f$ is differentiable then there exist $c$ such that (assume $h>t$)

$$f(x+h)-f(x+t)=f'(c)(h-t).$$ Thus

$$|f(x + h) - f(x + t) - f'(x)(h - t)| = |(f'(c) - f'(x))(h - t)|.$$ Now, since it is continously differentiable we have that as $h,t\to 0$ it is $f'(c)\to f'(x).$ Can you finish?

Conversely, assume the inequality holds. Writting $t=0$ we have that

$$\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-l\right|\le \epsilon.$$ Can we conclude that $l=f'(x)?$